# Avaje Ebean. ManyToMany deferred BeanSet

Tags: jpa, playframework, many-to-many, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am writing small app, using Play Framework 2.0 which uses Ebean as ORM.
So I need many-to-many relationship between User class and UserGroup class.
Here is some code:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Domain {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<UserGroup> groups = new HashSet();
}



@Entity
public class UserGroup extends Domain {

    @Id
    public Long id;     
    public String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")
    public Set<User> users = new HashSet();
}
```

Database scheme generator generates good scheme for that code with intermediate table and all work quite ok, till I using many-to-many.

So I am adding group in one request:

```
user.groups.add(UserGroup.find.byId(groupId));
user.update();
```

And trying output them to System.out in another:

```
System.out.println(user.groups);
```

And this returns:

> BeanSet deferred

Quick search show that BeanSet is lazy-loading container from Ebean. But seems like it doesn't work in proper way or I missed something important.

So is there any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to save associations manually

```
user.groups.add(UserGroup.find.byId(groupId));
user.saveManyToManyAssociations("groups");
user.update();
```

Comment: just a second ago I've explored it myself. Anyway, thank you one more time :)