# Ebean Play framework 2 many-to-many association loading

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

a bit of troubles from Play Framework 2 here.
There are two classes:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Domain {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public String phoneNumber;

    @Lob
    public String comment;

    @ManyToMany
    public Set<Band> groups = new HashSet();
}

@Entity
public class Band extends Domain {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    @Lob
    public String comment;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups")
    public Set<User> users = new HashSet();
}
```

And the problem with accessing User.groups. Doing

```
System.out.println(user.groups);
```

return the following:

> BeanSet deferred

exactly like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176013/avaje-ebean-manytomany-deferred-beanset) question. So the question is should I do something to make it loaded?

But running this code makes everything as expected.

```
Band.find.all();
System.out.println(user.groups);
```

What the reason of such behaviour?

P.S. Domain class is Model inheritor which keeps few static methods.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause, but it could be related. EBean deals with ManyToMany relationships differently... you need to explicitly set a cascade type along with some other differences (I dont remember all of them we stopped using it and switched to hibernate). One thing that you could try is to specify the mapping in User. Its odd that it works in Band though... Also maybe try to set a cascade type.

Comment: BTW: Whye does your model classes extends `Domain` instead of `Model` ?

Comment: @MarcusbiesiorBiesioroff, Domain is Model's inheritor to keep some stuff for dealing with my own generic-CRUD controller. I'll edit question a bit.

Comment: @JohnKane, adding cascade solve another bunch of problems. Thank you.

Comment: Care to share how you added cascade, that made it work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's MM relation so `user.groups` is `Set<Band>`, not just `Band` type. You need to iterate trough it...

First you need create a `Finder` in your classes (if you hadn't yet):

`User:`

```
public static Finder<Long, User> find 
        = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);
```

`Band:`

```
public static Finder<Long, Band> find 
        = new Finder<Long, Band>(Long.class, Band.class);
```

Next you need to fetch and iterate the allUsers as `List<User>` AND inside iterate the `Set<Band>` (available as `user.groups`):

```
List<User> allUsers = User.find.all();
for (User user : allUsers) {
    Logger.info("User's name is " + user.name);
    for (Band group : user.groups) {
        Logger.info(user.name + " in group " + group.name);
    }
}
```

Of course when you'll find single `Band` ie. with `Band.find.byId(1L)` you don't need to iterate it.

Don't forget to import the `Logger`:

```
import play.Logger;
```

It's better than `System.out.println()`

Comment: Take a look at my sample of iteration of the `users.groups` : `for (Band group : user.groups){}` it's working as excepted. Use `Logger.info(String)` instead `println(Object)`. In matter of next problem paste your controller's code somewhere and show me the whole thing. BTW the sample I showed you is built from your models and tested, so it's working correctly.

Comment: Is the reason in lazy-loading? Calling Set's toString() doesn't do real loading? Anyway thanks, it works good. Looks like your the only who uses play framework here :)